# when will the data explorer work?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

the data explorer SEDE is offline for a while, when will it work again?
here is a link showing it is offline:
https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/data.stackexchange.com.html

Answer (score 16):

Adding my update here as well:

**Update: 2020-02-29**

We are still dealing with hardware issues in Colorado and are hoping to have them resolved early next week.

In the meantime, we were able to temporarily create a version of Data Explorer that is running out of our NY data center. I setup up a new SQL instance and ran the refresh process yesterday afternoon. It should be available now for use. Once we get Colorado back in a working state, we'll most likely point things back there.

But go forth and query away.

---

I'll copy my answer from [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344297/164200):

> We're aware of the issue and are actively working on resolving it.
>
> For some context about what's going on.
>
> On 2020-02-26 we initialized maintenance on the core switches in our Colorado data center. The purpose of the maintenance was to push some software patches to the switches and should have been routine with a minor blip to the network out there. It turned out not that easy. Basically the software patches have resulted network instability for all the servers in CO.
>
> Unfortunately, SEDE runs solely out of the Colorado data center, and we haven't been able to stabilize the connection for the application. We have a ticket opened with Cisco to assist with the issue and are working to fix it as soon as possible.
>
> I'll update the answer once we have more details and a possible timeline for a resolution.
>
> We're sorry for the extended outage on it.

Comment: The "No OpenID endpoint found" issue has now been reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344386/284827).

Comment: Don't go looking for Windows updates. Wait for the notifications :) Better yet, don't use Windows.

Comment: I don't think the switches run Windows, @S.S.Anne.

Comment: @HansPassant should be fixed - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344444/164200